# Dividing header to 3 columns for mobile app (button,title,button)

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I want to create a div as header and divide in 3 columns and to place 2 buttons and one title inside of it in this order: 
Button1(position left)   Title(centered)  Button2 (position right)

This is my code for this div:

```
<div style="margin-top: 30px;border: solid 1px black;padding: 10px;">
            <div style="float: left;clear: both;"><span class="butonat">MENU</span></div>
            <div style="text-align: center;"><span style="color:#fff; text-shadow: none; font-family: Roboto;"> Kanali 1 </span></div>
            <div style="float: right;clear: both;"><span class="butonat">KANALI 2</span></div>
</div>
```

Below is the image of thet display:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNv60.png

I need to fix this using a solution which will work on mobile devices since its mobile app.

Comment: See the image.. the third button is not displayling properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a good practice but if you want to keep your current layout, the fix is to give your last div minus margin top as the following:

[**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/pg6fmy8e/)

```
 <div style="float: right;margin-top:-20px;"><span class="butonat">KANALI 2</span>
```

This is a practical example.
Give your wrapper 100% width and divide the 3 children's width in 100 (33.33333333333333). That will make sure the children will resize responsively.

[**JsFiddle Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/k6c302a7/)

```css
.header {
    margin-top: 30px;
    border: solid 1px black;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
}
.header div {
    float:left;
    width:33.33333333333333%;
}
.header .center {
    text-align:center;
}
.header .center span {
    color:#000;
    text-shadow: none;
    font-family: Roboto;
}
.header .right {
    text-align:right;
}
.header span {
    padding:10px;
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <div class="menu">
        <span class="butonat">MENU</span>
    </div>
    <div class="center">
        <span>Kanali 1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <span class="butonat">KANALI 2</span>
    </div>
</div>
```